# Problem with writing hashtag in Excel cell

Tags: excel

So I am having a problem with writing TwitterID (i.e. @DonaldTrump) into my Excel sheet. Whenever I try to write it on my cells, it prompts an error saying that "That function isn't valid.". I guess @ has some special meaning in Excel. Is there any way that I can avoid this error and write the TwitterIDs as text?

Comment: Add a `'` beforehand.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I enter an @ at the beginning of cell (when its not a formula)](https://superuser.com/q/428458/52365)

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is definitely not programming related. For future reference, please ask on [su].

Answer (score 1):

Source https://www.quora.com/What-does-the-symbol-do-in-Excel-It-keeps-showing-up-as-why-is-this-happening

> There was a period of time (I'd guess mid 80s to mid 90s) where a program called Lotus 123 was the de facto standard in spreadsheet programs. It operated with spreadsheet formulas much like the ones you see today. The at sign (@) was the way you indicated the start of a formula.
>
> Then, our friends at Microsoft decided they wanted to get into the spreadsheet game and came up with a product called Excel. Wanting to shift the balance of power, they made it easy for Lotus users to effortlessly adapt to the conceptually-similar Excel program. But people were used to typing formulas like @sum(a1:10), a result of 10 years of daily habit. They smartly allowed Lotus users to continue using their beloved @ sign, but they sneakily just substituted it with their proprietary equal sign (=) in the background, which is Excel's formula operator.
>
> The reason Excel is borking at you is because @, is instantly swapped out for =. The only correct suffix for = is a legitimate Excel formula. @craig is not one of them.
>
> Incidentally, the apostrophe (') tells Excel that whatever follows is text (as opposed to a numeral or formula) and will override the unwanted swapping effect. '@craig should display as you wish it to.
>
> Source: Lotus user for ten years, Excel user for 15 years.